# Uniform convergence of the given series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1794747/854335) answer, Using the similar proof, we can see the series uniformly converges on $K\subset (B(0,R)\cap\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb Z)$ with $d(K,\Bbb Z) =\delta>0$, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z}{n^2-z^2}$ converges. My question is can we drop this $d(K,\Bbb Z)=\delta>0$ condition? I don't know how to choose $z$ properly which shows that we can't drop that condition. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

If $K \subset (B(0,R)\cap (\mathbb  C \setminus Z)$ then $K$ has positive distance from $\{N,N+1,...\}$ for some $N$. So the proof in your link shows that the convergence is uniform.

Comment: I changed my question. Thanks. By the way, $d(K,\Bbb Z) = \delta>0$ means $d(k,N)\geq \delta>0$ for any $N\in\Bbb Z$ don't you think?

Comment: Yes, $d(k,N) \geq \delta$ for any $N$ What is your point? . My answer is still valid for your question. The condition $d(K,\mathbb Z) >0$ can be dropped.

Comment: Why is that? The lattice points contained in $K$ has distance zero.

Comment: Yes, but that does not affect uniform convergence.

Comment: In the proof in the link, it uses weierstrass M-test. To do that, we need $d(K,\Bbb Z) =\delta>0$ assumption. Why can we drop that condition? I can't see why it does not affect uniform convergence

Comment: Choose $N >R$. If $\sum\limits_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac z {n^{2}-z^{2}}$ converges uniformly then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac z {n^{2}-z^{2}}$ also converges uniformly. Apply the argument in the link to $\sum\limits_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac z {n^{2}-z^{2}}$, not to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac z {n^{2}-z^{2}}$. @barista